# repeating a program using while loop failed

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I coded a program that is meant to repeat itself over and over until the to_continue loop is broken by the input "N". However, it didn't seem to work.

```
phone_or_tablet=int(input("Phone or Tablet 1/2 "))
while phone_or_tablet not in [1,2]:
  print("Error")
  phone_or_tablet=int(input("Phone or Tablet 1/2 "))
else:
 if phone_or_tablet == 1:
    description=int(input("Compact, Clam Shell, Robo5-in, Robo6-in, Y-Standard or Y-Deluxe? 1/2/3/4/5/6 "))
    while description not in range (1,7,1):
      print("Error")
      description=int(input("Compact, Clam Shell, Robo5-in, Robo6-in, Y-Standard or Y-Deluxe? 1/2/3/4/5/6 "))
#some other programs (scroll down for the whole program)
print(sum(price))
to_continue=input("Continue? Y/N ")
while to_continue.capitalize() == "Y":
  phone_or_tablet=int(input("Phone or Tablet 1/2 "))
```

Output:

```
Phone or Tablet 1/2 1
Compact, Clam Shell, Robo5-in, Robo6-in, Y-Standard or Y-Deluxe? 1/2/3/4/5/6 1
#some other stuff
49.98
Continue? Y/N Y
Phone or Tablet 1/2 1
Phone or Tablet 1/2
```

whilst I meant for it to output

```
Phone or Tablet 1/2 1
Compact, Clam Shell, Robo5-in, Robo6-in, Y-Standard or Y-Deluxe? 1/2/3/4/5/6 1
#some other stuff
49.98
Continue? Y/N Y
Phone or Tablet 1/2 1
Compact, Clam Shell, Robo5-in, Robo6-in, Y-Standard or Y-Deluxe? 1/2/3/4/5/6 1
```

Full program if that's helpful:

```
typelst=["Compact", "Clam Shell", "Robo5-in", "Robo6-in", "Y-Standard", "Y-Deluxe"]
pricelst=[29.99,49.99,199.99,499.99,549.99,649.99]
typelst2=["Robo-8in", "Robo-10in", "Y-standard", "Y-deluxe"]
pricelst2=[149.99,299.99,499.99,599.99]
price=[]
phone_or_tablet=int(input("Phone or Tablet 1/2 "))
while phone_or_tablet not in [1,2]:
  print("Error")
  phone_or_tablet=int(input("Phone or Tablet 1/2 "))
else:
  if phone_or_tablet == 1:
    description=int(input("Compact, Clam Shell, Robo5-in, Robo6-in, Y-Standard or Y-Deluxe? 1/2/3/4/5/6 "))
    while description not in range (1,7,1):
      print("Error")
      description=int(input("Compact, Clam Shell, Robo5-in, Robo6-in, Y-Standard or Y-Deluxe? 1/2/3/4/5/6 "))    
    else:
      price.append(pricelst[description-1])
      sim_card=int(input("SIM card free or PAYG? 1/2 "))
      while sim_card not in range (1,3,1):
        print("Error")
        sim_card=input(int("SIM card none, free or PAYG? 0/1/2 "))
      else:
        if sim_card == 2:
          price.append(9.99)
  elif phone_or_tablet == 2:
    description=int(input("Robo-8in, Robo-10in, Y-standard or Y-deluxe? 1/2/3/4 "))
    while description not in range (1,5,1):
      print("Error")
      description=int(input("Robo-8in, Robo-10in, Y-standard or Y-deluxe? 1/2/3/4 "))
    else:
      price.append(pricelst2[description-1])
case=int(input("Standard or Luxury case? 1/2 "))
while case not in range (0,3,1):
  print("Error")
  case=int(input("Standard or Luxury case? 1/2 "))
else:
  if case==2:
    price.append(50)
charger=int(input("Car, Home charger or both? 1/2/3 "))
while charger not in range (0,4,1):
  print("Error")
  charger=int(input("Car, Home charger or both? 1/2/3 "))
else:
  if charger==1:
    price.append(19.99)
  elif charger==2:
    price.append(15.99)
    print(price)
  else:
    price.append(35.98)
print(sum(price))
to_continue=input("Continue? Y/N ")
while to_continue.capitalize() == "Y":
  phone_or_tablet=int(input("Phone or Tablet 1/2 "))
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated :)
Please comment if any of the explanations are unclear or if you need further details

Comment: Are you sure you meant to loop `while to_continue.capitalize() == "Y"` in the last loop? `to_continue` never changes inside the loop.

Comment: You have to wrap the whole program logic in one loop.

Comment: @ForceBru I'm about to write beneath this code some lines to determine whether the input of to_continue is valid and ask again for the input if not, so I thought that I should be using to_continue as the loop...

Comment: @ThomasSablik is there a way not to? Because I don't think that the code would be clean if so...

Comment: No, you want to repeat code so you have to wrap that code in a loop. You can use functions for cleaner code.

Comment: aha ok thank you very much :) I'll accept your answer when I'm allowed to in 4 min

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wrap the whole program logic in one loop.

```
while True:
  typelst=["Compact", "Clam Shell", "Robo5-in", "Robo6-in", "Y-Standard", "Y-Deluxe"]
  pricelst=[29.99,49.99,199.99,499.99,549.99,649.99]
  typelst2=["Robo-8in", "Robo-10in", "Y-standard", "Y-deluxe"]
  pricelst2=[149.99,299.99,499.99,599.99]
  price=[]
  phone_or_tablet=int(input("Phone or Tablet 1/2 "))
  while phone_or_tablet not in [1,2]:
    print("Error")
    phone_or_tablet=int(input("Phone or Tablet 1/2 "))
  else:
    if phone_or_tablet == 1:
      description=int(input("Compact, Clam Shell, Robo5-in, Robo6-in, Y-Standard or Y-Deluxe? 1/2/3/4/5/6 "))
      while description not in range (1,7,1):
        print("Error")
        description=int(input("Compact, Clam Shell, Robo5-in, Robo6-in, Y-Standard or Y-Deluxe? 1/2/3/4/5/6 "))    
      else:
        price.append(pricelst[description-1])
        sim_card=int(input("SIM card free or PAYG? 1/2 "))
        while sim_card not in range (1,3,1):
          print("Error")
          sim_card=input(int("SIM card none, free or PAYG? 0/1/2 "))
        else:
          if sim_card == 2:
            price.append(9.99)
    elif phone_or_tablet == 2:
      description=int(input("Robo-8in, Robo-10in, Y-standard or Y-deluxe? 1/2/3/4 "))
      while description not in range (1,5,1):
        print("Error")
        description=int(input("Robo-8in, Robo-10in, Y-standard or Y-deluxe? 1/2/3/4 "))
      else:
        price.append(pricelst2[description-1])
  case=int(input("Standard or Luxury case? 1/2 "))
  while case not in range (0,3,1):
    print("Error")
    case=int(input("Standard or Luxury case? 1/2 "))
  else:
    if case==2:
      price.append(50)
  charger=int(input("Car, Home charger or both? 1/2/3 "))
  while charger not in range (0,4,1):
    print("Error")
    charger=int(input("Car, Home charger or both? 1/2/3 "))
  else:
    if charger==1:
      price.append(19.99)
    elif charger==2:
      price.append(15.99)
      print(price)
    else:
      price.append(35.98)
  print(sum(price))
  to_continue=input("Continue? Y/N ")
  if to_continue.capitalize() == "N":
    break
```

Comment: and may I ask whether there is a shortcut to increase all indentations by one?

Comment: what about repl.it?

Comment: @runan I don't know repl.it. You have to read the doc.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider refactoring your program to separate functions wherever you repeat functionality.

Here, I've wrapped the main logic in a function that can be retried, as well as added a helper function `prompt` to ask the user for options from a list:

```
def choice(lst):
    """
    Prompt for an option from a list; return the option's index.
    :param lst: List of option strings.
    :return:
    """
    prompt = ", ".join(lst) + f"? [1..{len(lst)}] "
    while True:
        try:
            val = int(input(prompt))
            if 1 <= val <= len(lst):
                return val - 1
        except Exception as err:
            print(err)
        print("Try again.")


phone_types = [
    "Compact",
    "Clam Shell",
    "Robo5-in",
    "Robo6-in",
    "Y-Standard",
    "Y-Deluxe",
]
phone_prices = [29.99, 49.99, 199.99, 499.99, 549.99, 649.99]
tab_types = ["Robo-8in", "Robo-10in", "Y-standard", "Y-deluxe"]
tab_prices = [149.99, 299.99, 499.99, 599.99]


def prompt_price():
    price_components = []
    phone_or_tablet = choice(["Phone", "Tablet"])

    if phone_or_tablet == 0:  # Phone
        desc_choice = choice(phone_types)
        price_components.append(phone_prices[desc_choice])
        if choice(["No SIM", "Free SIM", "PAYG"]) == 2:
            price_components.append(9.99)
    else:
        desc_choice = choice(tab_types)
        price_components.append(tab_prices[desc_choice])

    if choice(["Standard Case", "Luxury Case"]) == 1:
        price_components.append(50)

    charger_choice = choice(
        ["Car Charger", "Home Charger", "Both Chargers"]
    )
    if charger_choice in (0, 2):
        price_components.append(19.99)
    if charger_choice in (1, 2):
        price_components.append(15.99)

    return sum(price_components)


def main():
    while True:
        price = prompt_price()
        print("Total price:", price)
        if input("Continue? Y/N ").upper() != "Y":
            break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```